# Django Queryset .last() method on processed queryset returning incorrect element

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following python code:

```
models.py
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I have two people added as `Persons` named 'Person 1' and 'Person 2', respectively. They both have the same order of 1.

```
views.py
def get_people():
    people = Person.objects.order_by('order')
    print(people)
    for p in people:
        print(p)
        if p == people.last():
            print ('Last Person')
```

Here's the result:

```
>>> get_people()
[<Person: Person 1>, <Person: Person 2>]
<Person 1>
u'Last Person'
<Person 2>
```

Took a little digging but I found this result and the underlying cause.

```
>>> people = Person.objects.order_by('order')
>>> print(people)
[<Person: Person 1>, <Person: Person 2>]
>>> print(people.first())
<Person 1>
>>> print(people.last())
<Person 1>
>>> people.first() == people.last()
True
>>> people[0]
<Person 1>
>>> people[1]
<Person 2>
```

I looked at the source code and it appears the last() method is just running `reverse()` with the same ordering I've selected. Since the two elements have the same order number of 1, the reverse method is returning the exact same list as the original, assuming because when sorting reverse, the same rule applies that in a tie, the element with lowest record id is first, instead of truly reversing the list that is already retrieved. I don't understand why they don't just take the list of elements already retrieved and get the last one from the index. I tried using the [-1] negative index to get at it, but that is not implemented and raises an exception.

So can somebody explain why this was coded that way? It could be problematic if several of your elements share a the same value for the property being ordered by. Especially if the queryset is accessed more than once with a subsequent call to last(). Is it for performance or for some other issue that I am not seeing? Instead of using the last() method in this use-case, I am simply doing this comparison, instead:

```
if p == people[len(people) - 1]:
```

And that works. And in this case, I know the people is not empty so we won't get an IndexError -  if it were empty, the code would never be executed in the loop. A general case could be:

```
l = len(people)
return None if l == 0 else return people[l -1]
```

Or:

```
try:
    l = len(people)
    return people[l - 1]
except IndexError:
    return None
```

Can you share some insight on this behavior, please? The only thing in the docs for Django states the last() method is just like first() but returns the last element of a queryset. In this case it is not functioning as described.  This behavior puzzled me. I thought it would just take the last element from the current list, not make a new reversed list and get the first element of that.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why don't you just define a better ordering?  The way you have it they're a tie, so the idea of first and last is somewhat meaningless here..

Comment: That was just an example. The people were supposed to be ordered correctly when added, but somehow got off track. There are plenty of real-world examples when ordering on a field that may have multiple records with the same. Say for a birth date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone put any thought into this edge-case, the reasons would most likely be a combination of consistency and performance.

First of all, you generally can't evaluate the entire queryset just to get the last element without imposing a huge performance penalty. `Person.objects.order_by('order').last()` should get one row, not the entire table -- which could contain millions of rows. So in case of an unevaluated queryset, you need to reverse the order in SQL and get the top element. This will always suffer from the problem you describe.

You could get the last element in the cache only if the queryset is evaluated, but that would mean you get inconsistent results. Take the following code:

```
people = Person.objects.order_by('order')
p1 = people.last()
bool(people)
p2 = people.last()
```

In your example, `p1` would be `<Person 1>`. However, if you take the last element of the cache if the queryset is evaluated, `p2` would suddenly be `<Person 2>`, just because the cache is filled. This kind of self-inconsistency makes the job of a developer very difficult.

While this might not be very intuitive, it is the best way to translate the `.last()` method in an actual database query and get both acceptable performance and self-consistent results. The fact that unordered or partially ordered result sets have an *undefined* order (which may even change arbitrarily between queries) is a well-understood aspect of SQL, so overall this is the path of [least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: Ah ha. Got it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem with the code is that you are sorting in ascending order leaving it up to Django to figure out how to handle a tie breaker between the two.  The equivalent in SQL to what you wrote in your `get_people()` method is as follows:

`SELECT * FROM Person ORDER BY order ASC`

So in the case of there being two people both with the same "order" value, your results will never come back correctly.  Instead, you want a query that looks more akin to this:

`SELECT * FROM Person ORDER BY order, last_name, first_name` (assuming you want to sort by last name first after order.

I ran into a problem like this with an app I designed once and the solution is pretty straight forward.  Instead of beating your head trying to figure out the underlying "problem" with the Django API (even though realistically it's only as smart as the design of the tables), you can use something like this:

```
views.py
def get_people():
    people = Person.objects.order_by('order', 'last_name', 'first_name')
    print(people)
    for p in people:
        print(p)
        if p == people.last():
            print ('Last Person')
```

Notice in the line where we are "creating the query" through Django I included multiple columns.  This will resolve your tie problem so if two people have the same order, it will then sort by Last Name.

Comment: Yes, I understand and thank you for your time answering. In this case, I only want to order by the order field, and there are many cases when you wouldn't want to have an any extra ordering, but I guess you could add the id or something. That seems silly to have to do that for every queryset I write that I want a last on, though. I am more curious why they chose to write it out this way, or if it was just arbitrary. Seems less efficient to me to reverse the list rather than just getting the length and getting the element at the end of the list.

Comment: Unfortunately that's probably something you'd have to ask the developers.  I would assume the answer they give may be similar in that they would say it's a "what you are sorting on problem" more so than their "how we are sorting" issue.  Remember that the query you are building in Django is simply a way to translate to SQL so the limitation may not even be on Django. :-)

Comment: I hear that. Thanks for your insight.